# Get the margins defined by a printer in html, php or javascript

Tags: html, css, printing, margins

I am doing a project which requires to have a 20mm white area around a print page, with a 10mm border within that.

I have these set up using `<div>`s and everything looks fine on the HTML page - but when I go to print, I get the extra 4-5mm margin which I cannot print on (as it is defined by each printer) added to the left and the top pushing everything over to the right, and partly onto a second page. I imagine it is just taken off the right side and the bottom part is pushed onto a second page.

What I want to do is get the exact mm that are being added onto the left right top and bottom of the page and take that away from my 20mm. As I cannot guarantee which printer will be used with the page, I cannot guarantee that all the margins will be the same size as mine.

I cannot use shrink to fit on IE, because I need the measurements to be precise on where things are placed and the size, and as it is not supported by IE6 - which could be used, as it is a requirement of my application that the client is IE (don't ask me why it just has to be that way).

Comment: There is no tax on punctuation, capital letters or new-lines, you know.

Answer (score 4):

Printing from browsers is hellishly ugly, and you have essentially no way to affect the output except HOPE that the browser will honor a @print css styling. There's also no way to query for printer capabilities so you can't find out what its "dead zones" are on the page edges.

If you need to generate a pixel-perfect layout on paper, then use a PDF.